# Sum in HTML,jQuery anf Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add values entered by user in a text box and print via a variable named "sum".
The values entered are given to same variable i.e. first time value of x is 4, next time user enters the value of x =5; then sum should be 4+5=9
But the output is 45 ,i.e it keeps on printing values next to each other.
Is there any way , I can print my desired output.
My code is attached with this.

'

```
</script>

</head>
 <body>
<div id="header">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;"><center><img src="ccc.jpg" /></center></h1>
</div>
<div id="menu" style="background-color:white ;height:500px;width:150px;float:left;">


</div>
<h3>
<center>
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>It's Cricket Time - Score as many runs as possible</legend>
    <label>Enter Your Number</label>
    <input type =" number" name="number" id= "test1" />
    <input type ="button" id= "tab1" value="Click Me" onclick= "out()" />    
    <br>
    <label>Your Score:</label>
    <h5 id ="output"></h5>
 </fieldset>
</form>

<br>
</center></h3>
<script>
var sum=0;
function out()
 {

    var x= $("#test1").val();
    var array=[0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6];

    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20));

    //if( x !==0 || x !==1 || x !==2 || x !==4 || x !==6 )
    //{
    //  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="Enter a legitimate number!!";
    //  window.setTimeout("location.reload()", 500);
    //}

    //else
    {       

        if(x == array[y] )
            {   
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="YOU ARE OUT";
            }
        else
            {
                sum=sum+x;
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=sum;

            }
    document.getElementById("test1").value='';
   //   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=sum;
        console.log(array[y]);
}

    }


  </script>
 <div id="footer" style="background-color:#0099FF;clear:both;text-align:center;">
            Copyright © rooparshkalia productions</div>
 </body>
   </html>   '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are being treated as `string` data types. They need to be treated as `int` data types. Javascript is a dynamic language and the type is inferred at run time.

`document.getElementById("test1").value=''` change to `document.getElementById("test1").value=0`

I didn't look at your code but if that doesn't work then use parseInt with a base 10 radix

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

`parseInt(string,10)`

Answer (score 0):

When you write `sum = sum + x;` it concatenates `sum` and `x` as string. Try this and please let me know if this code works.

```
else
{
    sum = sum + parseInt(x); // or sum += parseInt(x);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery **parseInt** function to parse string to int.

```
    var sum = 0;
    function out() {

        var x = $("#test1").val();
        var array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6];

        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20));
        if (x == array[y]) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "YOU ARE OUT";
        }
        else {
            sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(x);
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;

        }
        document.getElementById("test1").value = '';
        console.log(array[y]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Hiren for your help, it's working...... can u also suggest changes which i should make in commented out portion. It's showing same message "Enter a legitimate number" for any number we enter...